# C++ std::string initialization using new operator function

Tags: c++, malloc, overloading, new-operator, stdstring

Have a basic snippet of initialization a std::string variable, and track the memory usage of program using overloaded new operator function as below:

```
static uint32_t s_AllocCount = 0;

// Overload of new operator.
void* operator new(size_t size) {

    s_AllocCount++;
    std::cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes\n";

    return malloc(size);
}
```

**Example-1:** When initialized below in main:

```
int main()
{
    std::string name = "Hello World 1234";
    std::cout<<"No. of allocations="<<s_AllocCount<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
  Allocating 17 bytes
  No. of allocations=1
```

**Example-2:** When initialized below in main:

```
int main()
{
    std::string name = "Hello World";
    std::cout<<"No. of allocations="<<s_AllocCount<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
  No. of allocations=0
```

**Query**

Why the overloaded new operator is not called in the 2nd example where the length of the string is less than 16 bytes/characters. Where does the initialization of string memory happen in 2nd example.

Comment: Look up SSO (small/short string optimization). Short strings don't require dynamic memory allocation. This is a nice introduction : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230803-00/?p=108532

Comment: Be very careful when you write your own `operator new`; there is no guarantee that writing to `std::cout` won't do any allocations, and if it does, you've got an infinite recursion. Use C-styple IO (`printf`) instead.